# SwiftUI Inspector gone in Project

Tags: xcode, swiftui

In one of my Xcode projects, the SwiftUI Inspector won't show anymore.

Example:
[image]

When I create a new project, I have the inspector:

[image]

Any idea what is causing this? Can I maybe reset the settings of the project?

Comment: That is Xcode issue. Try close and reopen

Comment: I did a complete reinstall and that didn't even fix it :(

Comment: Do you have Canvas opened? Those menu items are not shown when Canvas is closed.

Comment: Yes, The Canvas must be open to get it work. Nothing else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must have Canvas opened to have SwiftUI context menu items in Editor (including SwfitUI Inspector)

[image: Activating canvas]

Answer (score 2):

**XCode 12 Update**

Even after enabling the Canvas if the *inspect* option is not showing up because, Its been renamed to *Show SwiftUI Inspector*

**Canvas**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmpVW.png

**Editor**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D74Ml.png

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue where I couldn't see Show SwiftUI Inspector on Xcode 14.2. Turned out that there are couple things you need to do.

1. Have turn on Canvas if it's not already on. Go to `Editor -> Canvas`

[image]

2. In Content View, change it to `Selectable`

[image]

3. CMD + Click on an element. Now you should see `Show Swift UI Inspector...`

[image]