# How do you use the "Embed in button" action in Xcode 11.0

Tags: xcode, actionscript-3, swiftui

This is a very general question for everyone who uses Xcode 11. I am trying to find the action that will allow me to use the "Embed in button" if you know of any ways please leave a comment below. I have tried Command + Click & Control + Click and neither work or direct me to the action

Comment: I assume my answer in [SwiftUI Inspector gone in Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58888687/12299030) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Version 11.4.1 of XCode

The option to: Embed in Button isn't available anymore in XCode.

Anyway, you can do this instead:

1. Click the "+" (Library Button)
2. Click on "Show the views library" and search for Button
3. Drag and drop the Button wherever you need it
4. Cut, Paste your code inside of the brachets

   [1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfePJ.png)
   [2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncTP0.jpg)
   [3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcGCc.png)
   [4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CGYY.png)

I hope this can help you.