# iOS SwiftUI how to bring up extra actions like "Embed in VStack" when interacting with code?

Tags: swiftui, ios13, xcode11

I am looking at [this SwiftUI tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3715234-swiftui-getting-started) and it suggests I can see extra actions upon Command-Clicking the SwiftUI elements **in code**. In my Xcode, this jumps me to the class definition.

[image]

I see there's an option in XCode 11.0 t change the Option key to show SwiftUI inspector, however, this still does not let me modify SwiftUI code elements using actions like "Embed in VStack"

**How can I get both inspector and extra SwiftUI actions when interacting with SwiftUI Code (not the preview)?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Canvas must be opened, please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58888687/12299030) for details.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Extra SwiftUI actions** show when Canvas is opened (shortcut: Option-Command-Enter or ⌥+⌘+↵):

[image: when canvas close]
*canvas is closed*

[image: when canvas is open]
*canvas is opened*

Comment: It is still not showing for me even when my canvas is showing.

Comment: @ScottyBlades what Xcode version do you use? Have you tried to relaunch it?

Comment: Version 12.4 (12D4e), yes I've tried relaunching it. It only shows intermittently/randomly.

Comment: Thank you for reminding `when Canvas is opened`

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me on `macOS 10.15.5` and `Xcode 11.4.1`.

The *Good news* is that you can get it via a shortcut of `[Command][Shift][Left Click]` on a `SwiftUI` element or by clicking `Show Code Actions` on the right click menu.

[image: Right click > Show Code Actions]

Comment: This was helpful to me as I had the same problem. Then, I found that if I go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Navigate and change the command click behavior to Selects Code Structure, I can use command+click to get there too.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using the mouse, I recommend using the Xcode hotkey for bringing up code actions. Navigate to Preferences -> Key Bindings and search for `Show Code Actions`. You'll see the preset hotkey which you can then customize. My default key binding was `Shift`+`Command`+`A`. Just make sure you cursor is over the intended element when you press the hotkey.

[image]

Comment: This works on Xcode 13.4 (CMD+SHIFT+A)

Comment: Nathan, do you know if there's a way to set a shortcut for a specific code action?

Comment: @zh Some of the code actions are bindable such as "Jump to Definition" and "Show SwiftUI Inspector" but from what I can tell Xcode does not yet support shortcuts for things like "Embed in HStack" etc. I would love to be wrong about this.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the command click behavior where you were looking under Xcode -> Preferences, Navigate tab.

[image]

Rather unintuitively, if you pick "Selects Code Structure", then `command`+`click` will bring up the SwiftUI menu options you're looking for (granted the canvas is open).

If you do this, you can still jump to definition via `control`+`command`+`click`

Conversely, if you'd prefer to continue to use `command`+`click` to jump to definition, you can instead use `control`+`command`+`click` to bring up the SwiftUI menu options.

Comment: Nice find! I want the SwiftUI less than I want jump to definition otherwise this would be a winner for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Command clicking on a view will not work in Xcode 12.2 and 12.3 (under MacOS 10.15.5) if you have your preferences different than Xcode expects.

You have to change your `Navigation` preferences for `Command-click on Code:` to `Selects Code Structure` before the proper menu will appear when you command click on a `View`.

To change this. press command , to open your preferences and select the `Navigation` button.  The option you need to change is in the first popup menu.